# how to store php object to access its data on click with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter, onclick

I'm trying to figure out the least obtrusive and least computationally expensive way to store PHP objects coming from my MySQL database such that their data can be rendered by JavaScript on click by a user.

Currently, I'm storing the data as custom attributes on a button. But this generates a lot of code and I've heard is "slow". I'm wondering if I should JSON encode my PHP object, `$items` (see below), and how that JavaScript would then look. Note I'm using Codeigniter for the PHP so that's what up with the alternate `foreach` loop syntax.

Here's where I'm at so far with the HTML/PHP:

```
<img id="img"></img><a id="url"></a> <!--elements where data is rendered on click-->
<? foreach($items as $item):?>  
<button data-id="<?=$item->id?>" data-url="<?=$item->url?>" data-img="<?=$item->img?>">click<?=$item->id?></button>
<?endforeach;?>
```

And here's my JS:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){
   var $this=$(this), id=$this.data('id'), url=$this.data('url'), img=$this.data('img');
   $('#img').attr('src', img);
   $('#url').attr('href', url).html(url);
});
```

Most of my site's data is coming from PHP via MySQL and I've long been confused by the issue of when should I convert that data to a JavaScript array/JSON or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `json_encode` your `$items` array (assuming it only consists of data you will want in JS), you can assign this to a JS variable:

```
<script>var items = <?php echo json_encode($items); ?></script>
```

You can then remove the `data-url` and `data-img` attributes. Then, within your JS code:

```
var $this = $(this), id = $this.data('id'), url = items[id].url, img = items[id].img;
// the rest of your code
```

Edit: when you move the click handler in a separate file, you would get something like this:

```
function setup_click(items) {
    var $img = $('#img'), $url = $('#url');

    $('button').click(function(evt) {
           var id = $(this).data('id'),
           url = String(items[id].url),
           img=String(items[id].img);
       $url.attr('href', url).html(url);         
           $img.attr('src', img);
    });
}
```

here's a JSfiddle showing off the javascript/JSON part: http://jsfiddle.net/fz5ZT/55/

To call this in one shot from your template:

```
<script src="[your ext script file path].js"></script>
<script>setup_click(<?php echo json_encode($items); ?>);</script>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: hi Jack, thanks for your help, can you add to your JS code to show me how the click function factors in? i'd like to put the click function in an external JS file. So, this would mean I have 2 sets of script tags?

Comment: hi Jack, one more question: i've never understood why people put "evt" in click `function(evt)` if one subsequently doesn't call `evt`. In fact, i'm not even sure of a common event that people would commonly need access to inside the button click. Meaning, what would "blahblah" typically be here: `evt.blahblah`?

Comment: jQuery defines a unified event handling mechanism you can use, check it out on their website :) for instance, you can stop the click event from performing its default behaviour by calling evt.preventDefault() - try this on an anchor with href #. The address bar would normally show the # when clicked. Try it :)

Comment: thanks! oh yeah, evt.preventDefault(), duh, tim! i'm also still a little confused on the php. `$items` doesn't have the `id` as keys so the "id" part of `items[id].img` doesn't exist. here's where i'm at so far: `<?foreach($library as $row):?>
 <? $id=$row->folder_id;?>
 <?endforeach;?>
<?$items=array($id =>$library);  echo json_encode($items); ?>`. That's not quite right, but would you mind helping to figure out how to define the `[id]` key?

Comment: Hmm okay, inside foreach you should instead have $items[$row->folder_id] = $row;

Comment: thanks, closer but now i can't get the JS to cooperate. Here's what calling console.log(items) looks like inside the click function: `{"89":{"img":"/images/89.jpg","url":"http://site89.com"}, {"22":{"img":"/images/22.jpg","url":"http://site22.com"}`. The error message says, *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined"*.  So it looks like the problem is that the `id = $(this).data('id')` is getting assigned by the click function but it isn't getting set equal to `items[id]`. Do i need quotations around either `id` variable?

Comment: note that manually plugging in a value like this: `var img=items[89].img` still says img is undefined

Comment: You have to cast 89 to string first. Is $(this).data('id') defined btw?

Comment: yes, `$(this).data('id')` is defined and is equal to 89 when i click button #89. How do I cast `items` or `items[id]` to string? I tried both inside the `String()` function but `img` is still undefined. Can you just add to your answer what that code what look like? thanks!

Comment: i've also tried, `toString()`, `JSON.Stringify()`. I've also set id=items[id]. I gotta be close, just can't quite figure it out...frustrating....

Comment: Hi Jack, the following does work: img=String(item[id].img). I updated your answer. Thanks again for all your help.